# Pointer as a function argument?

Tags: c, pointers

The output of code is **11,11,undefined value**.......please explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int **const p); 

int main() 
{ 
   int i = 10; 
   int *p = &i; 
   f(&p); 
   printf("%d ", *p); 
   printf("%d ", *p); 
} 

void f(int **const p) 
{ 
   int j = 11; 
   *p = &j; 
   printf("%d ", **p); 
}
```

Comment: On what wicked system does `%d` print `"undefined value"`??

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant : well, after all - it's undefined behaviour. :)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Exactly... :P

Comment: oh, point of order, terrible code.

Answer (score 8):

It's [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you set `*p` to point to a local variable, and once the function exits all local variables goes out of scope which give you a dangling pointer.

---

What *really* happens is that the memory formerly occupied by the local variable `j` is reused by the next function call, so you will print whatever value that function set that memory to.

Comment: It literally makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @Jefffrey You don't need a `return` statement to return from a function, a function returns automatically once it ends.

Comment: @Jefffrey Through the "output" argument `p`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, of course functions return when they are finished, but unless you explicitly do so, they return nothing. Not even a null value. They return void, a clear lack of anything. If I had a penny for everything they returned, I'd have no pennies. I could have an infinite collection of what they return and still have exactly what one call returns, nothing. If an infinite number of monkeys called this function and infinite number of times they would for ever be disappointed by the lack of value that is return and be forever longing for yellow phallic fruit.

Comment: it's a void function. it is supposed to return nothing.

Comment: @thecoshman There are multiple ways to "return" something from a function, not only from a `return` statement. Another example would be to set a global variable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg IMHO "returns something" is not the same as "has an output parameter". But I reckon it's just my opinion.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `return` has very clear meaning. You are referring to side effects, which you do not address within your answer.

Comment: @Jefffrey For me, saying that a function "returns" something, I see it as the function gives you back a something, how it give you the something is not important. However, I have reworded my answer to hopefully end the confusion.

Comment: `return` is a keyword with specific meanings. Also, out parameters do not give you back something, they take something and f... muck it up. Of course, a return value might not be a different 'data thing', it could be a mutated version of something passed in.

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
   *p = &j;
```

the scope of `j` is smaller than the scope of `p`. When the function `f` returns, the value stored in `p` is no longer valid. Hence undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Scope of variable is local to function in which it is defined.In your case j is local to function f.Variable j is no longer visible outside function f.and hence p becomes dangling pointer.If you are expecting output as 11 11 11 then you have to declare j as a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you exit function `f()`, the variable `j` goes out of scope, yet the pointer `p` is *still pointing to that memory address*. This is Undefined Behaviour.

Simplified inline version of your code, commented with what is happening:

```
int main() 
{ 
  int *p;             //create pointer
  { 
    int j = 11;       //create j in local scope
    p = &j;           //set p to point at j (refered to as address A from now)
    printf("%d ", *p);//print value at A  "11 "
  }                   //j goes out of scope
  printf("%d ", *p);  /*print value at A  "11 11 "  
                       ***UB: as memory at A is not used to store j any more,
                       printf() can use it to store variables for its own use*/
  printf("%d ", *p);   /*print value at A  "11 11 GARBAGE"  
                        ***UB: as memory at A is not used to store j any more,
                        the previous printf() call touched A at some point
                        changing the contents (and thus the read value)*/
}
```

To be honest, I'm suprised that the call to the first `printf()` didn't clobber the memory before outputting it.

You can't rely on the second `printf` outputting the 'correct value'. Even in this simple example, the behavior seen is dictated only by the implementation, and a different compiler will quite likely handle this differently.
Just by changing the code, it is *very* likely that the output would change, for example, declaring a new variable before the `printf` would likely overwrite the memory and stop the output from either being correct.